# Unable to Instantiate activity ComponentInfo - Android

Tags: android

I have read several errors of this kind, but I do not find a solution to my particular problem. My activities are all added to my manifest, and I did not start the emulator from an abstract class. My app used to work, until I tried to add spinners to it (which I probably did not do right). I run the app and it crashes before it even opens. Any idea what is wrong? I am a beginner, so please share plain language, thanks very much.

**So here is my main activity:**

```
package com.noni.gridimagesearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    EditText etQuery;
    GridView gvResults; 
    Button btnSearch;
    ArrayList<ImageResult> imageResults = new ArrayList<ImageResult>();
    ImageResultArrayAdapter imageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        setupViews();
        imageAdapter = new ImageResultArrayAdapter(this, imageResults);
        gvResults.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        gvResults.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View parent, 
                    int position, long rowId) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                        ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                ImageResult imageResult = imageResults.get(position);
                i.putExtra("result", imageResult);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        GridView gvResults = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvResults);
        gvResults.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int TotalItemsCount) {
                customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            }
        });

        setupAdvancedOptionsListener();

    } //end onCreate method

    Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);
    public void setupAdvancedOptionsListener() {
        advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent (SearchActivity.this, AdvancedOptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }

    public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    public void setupViews() {
        etQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQuery);
        gvResults = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvResults);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);  
    }

    public void onImageSearch(View v) {
        imageResults.clear();
        String query = etQuery.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for " + query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        int offset = 0;
        client.get("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?rsz=8&" +
        "start=" + offset + "&v=1.0&imgsz=medium&q=" + Uri.encode(query), 
                new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                JSONArray imageJsonResults = null;
                try {
                    imageJsonResults = response.getJSONObject("responseData")
                            .getJSONArray("results");

                    imageAdapter.addAll(ImageResult
                            .fromJSONArray(imageJsonResults));
                    Log.d("DEBUG", imageResults.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Here is my activity with the spinners:**

```
package com.noni.gridimagesearch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdvancedOptionsActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner colorFilter, imageSize, imageType;
    //private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_options);

        colorFilter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color_filter);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.color_filter, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        colorFilter.setAdapter(adapter);
        colorFilter.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        imageSize = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.image_size);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.image_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        imageSize.setAdapter(adapter2);
        imageSize.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        imageType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.image_type);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.image_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        imageType.setAdapter(adapter3);
        imageType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }   

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,
            long l) {
        TextView myText = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected " + myText.getText(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.advanced_options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

**Here is the LogCat:**

```
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.noni.gridimagesearch/com.noni.gridimagesearch.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at com.noni.gridimagesearch.SearchActivity.<init>(SearchActivity.java:66)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
04-01 06:43:26.638: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     ... 11 more
```

**Here is my activity_search.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etQuery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/query_hint"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onImageSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/search_label" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvResults"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/advancedSearch"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etQuery"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:background="#D3F5F4"
        android:text="@string/advanced_search"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: thanks for checking, I posted it above.

Comment: post `activity_search.xml`

Comment: thanks, just added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess line 66 is

```
Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);
```

You do not have a button with id `advancedSearch` in `activity_search.xml`. SO initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

Edit:

After looking at the source code. It looks like you have the Button initialized outside `onCreate`. Initialize it inside `onCreate` and make sure you have the braces `}` in the right place.

It looks like you have misplaced `}`.

Get rid of this

```
setupAdvancedOptionsListener();
```

and this

```
public void setupAdvancedOptionsListener() {
```

Change to

```
Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);
advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AdvancedOptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
 } // brace of onCreate end here.
```

Edit:

What you could have done. Call this in onCreate

```
  setupAdvancedOptionsListener();
  } // end of onCreate
```

Then

```
  public void setupAdvancedOptionsListener() {
     Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);
     advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AdvancedOptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks, although I do have a button in the activity_search.xml named advancedSearch...

Comment: @NoniA. i edited my answer. its a case of msplaced `}`

Comment: @NoniA. you need to get rid of `setupAdvancedOptionsListener();` and have the brace of `}` at the end

Comment: omg, thank you so much!!! seriously i spent about 10 hours on this problem and was about to lose all hair. ;) although i was always shown by my teacher to create external methods (outside of onCreate) then call the method inside of onCreate.. did i do something wrong by doing that you think? it usually works... maybe i made errors.

Comment: @NoniA. You implement a interface OnClickListener. In your case you use a annonymous inner class. Its not wrong to call a method. But you need to initialize your views after setting the layout to the activity and inside a method. What you should have done is call `setupAdvancedOptionsListener();` in onCreate and move the code that i mentioned in your method.

Comment: OH!!! thanks a lot, that really helps. i didn't realize i had to get the Button id call from inside of the `setupAdvancedOptionsListener();` method... thanks again! this really helps my future understanding too. :)

Comment: @NoniA. there are few more ways to do the same. Declare `advancedSearch ` as a instance variable. Initialize button in `onCreate`. just use `advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` in the method. Its just a matter of convinience and matter of how readable is the code. Generally initialize views in onCreate as it s called once during the lifecycle of the activity

Comment: Interesting... yeah, this stuff always gets me confused, but i think one day i will get used to the many ways of doing things. very good to know though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Initilize below **Button inside OnCreate**

```
Button advancedSearch;
```

inside **OnCreate**

```
 advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);

 advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AdvancedOptionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I tried putting that line in onCreate, but then it says my variable is unused... so I added a `Button advancedSearch;` declaration at the top, but that did not help, it still says it is unused... also the app still crashes. :/

Comment: @NoniA. I edited my ans after initilize `Button` add ClickListener

Answer (score 1):

You have setup all views in onCreate() by setupViews()

```
public void setupViews() {
    etQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQuery);
    gvResults = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvResults);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);  
}
```

the individual code segment like:

```
//GridView gvResults = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvResults);
    gvResults.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
```

and

```
//Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);
public void setupAdvancedOptionsListener() {
```

are not necessary. Just delete them.

Edit:

declare `Button advancedSearch;` as a member variable.

and add `advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);` in setupViews() method.

Comment: thanks Euporie, how can you tell if there are unnecessary methods created? my teacher always showed us to create methods outside of onCreate, and then call them inside of onCreate (maybe to make the code cleaner?) but generally, you were right. it was the Button one that was the problem.

Comment: @NoniA. setupViews() method can make sure all views have been initialized well. I prefer to do like this in my project. But you have declare `GridView gvResults;` as a member variable, then in `GridView gvResults = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvResults);
    gvResults.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {`, "gvResults" is not the member variable, it's a local variable you have just decalred above it.

Comment: @NoniA. Sorry, I find a mistake in my answer. If you delete `Button advancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedSearch);` immediately, then `public void setupAdvancedOptionsListener() {
        advancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` will crash with NullPointException. I have edited my answer.